# How could I have 2 different route keys names for my Post model? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I've made a simple Laravel CRUD, and I'm stuck on a problem.
My posts have a `slug` column and a `uuid` column in the table in which they are stored. I've binded the routes to the `PostController` using

```php
Route::resource("posts", "PostController");
```

I want to be able to call the `show` route by using the slug in the URL, (`example.com/posts/all-about-my-new-banana-maker`), but to be able to call the `edit` route by using the UUID (`example.com/posts/ddd83f7b-9c73-11eb-93c2-e55e28ace783/edit`)
I've tried editing my `Post` model and changing `getRouteKeyName`:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // Set mass-assignable fields
    protected $fillable = ["title", "content", "category", "image", "slug", "uuid"];

    /**
     * Get the route keyfor the model
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return "slug";
    }
}
```

I can only see to have UUID or slug, not both at the same time. How could I make it so that *both* UUID and slug retrieve my post?

Comment: maybe you need to create custom routes for this, resource route works with only primary id like show method will be like `posts/show/1` and edit will be like `posts/1/edit`

Comment: @Psycho Not true. Resource routes jsut provide some default routes using convention. Route model binding works with the primary key unless overridden. If you don't use route model binding you can pass anything as the resource identifier to a resource route method.

Comment: okay, I had little knowledge about RouteKeyName(), apart from that, for his case, he needs to make custom route, right?

Comment: Nope. The route key is only used if you use route model binding. So if you don't type hint your route method parameters, laravel will not try to map the route parameter to a model. You would then be responsible for finding the correct model in the database though.

Comment: You were right @Psycho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass extra [route parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters), then you need to define an another route for that :

```
Route::get("posts/{uuid}/{slug}", "PostController@data");
```

And your controller will be looked like :

```
public function data($uuid, $slug) {
    // You can access $uuid and $slug here
}
```

Comment: Nicw to hear that it worked, happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove any type hints from your methods, or override the route model binding in your `RouteServiceProvider`.

#### Remove type hinting

```
public function show($post)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug', $post)->firstOrFail();
}

public function edit($post)
{
    $post = Post::where('uuid', $post);
}
```

#### Override route model binding

Add something like the following to the `boot` method of the `RouteServiceProvider`.

```
Route::bind('post', function ($value){
    return Post::where('slug', $value)->orWhere('uuid', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
```

You still use type hinting if you override the route model binding in the `RouteServiceProvider`.